# IBM Watson Personality Service & Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, ibm-watson, personality-insights

We have been using the Watson personality service to analyse facebook posts of users who interact with our app. We provide a facebook login, the person logs into facebook and we capture the text of their timeline, then send it to watson for analysis (with consent).

This process works fine but recently the facebook graph API has asked for a "app review". I went though the whole process but my submission failed for no obvious reason, also facebook's feeback is frankly useless.

My question is... has anyone else been through the facebook app review process and willing to give any tips on getting through the challenge.

Thanks, 
Simon

Website Example: https://personality-insights-demo.ng.bluemix.net/

More Information: https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/personality-insights/

Example big 5: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/personality-insights/models.html#models

Facebook API: https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: You used the wrong channel. Here you need to provide code. It is better to paste the code than using urls. Search for another more suitable channel on stack exchange ;)

Comment: _“and we capture the text of their timeline,”_ - by requesting `user_posts` permission, presumably? _“then send it to watson for analysis (with consent)”_ - not an allowed use case for that permission to begin with, as https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_posts very explicitly mentions. Your users can “consent” all day long if they want to, doesn’t matter. This is the review process working as it should - by preventing your app from going live with functionality it is not supposed to provide in the first place.